# Roots of unity over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, roots, extension-field, totient-function, cyclotomic-polynomials

I want to show the following proposition from Algebra, Hungerford V.8.9.

If $n > 2$ and $\xi$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity over $\mathbb{Q}$, then
 $[\mathbb{Q}(\xi + \xi^{-1}) : \mathbb{Q}]= \frac{\varphi(n)}{2}$, where $\varphi(n)$ denotes the Euler's totient or phi function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: Under the Galois correspondence prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})$ corresponds to the subgroup $\langle -1 \rangle$ of order $2$ of $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q}) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/n)^*$. Since $-1$ corresponds to the complex conjugation, you have to prove $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta+\zeta^{-1}) = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta) \cap \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Since $[\mathbb{Q}(\xi):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\xi):\mathbb{Q}(\xi+\xi^{-1})][\mathbb{Q}(\xi+\xi^{-1}):\mathbb{Q}]$, and $[\mathbb{Q}(\xi):\mathbb{Q}]=\phi (n)$ I understand why the subgroup under the Galois correspondance have to be of order 2. But how do you know it is $\langle-1\rangle$? And how do you prove it? Sorry if i am doing stupid questions...i'm a little tired now but i want to understand this ;)

Comment: I have already given a hint how to prove it. Try it!

Comment: Wow. A hint and 7 hours of sleep helps a lot. Now I can see it, thank you!